# Изменить регистр только 1 буквы в нескольких фразах после определенного символа

Tags: регулярные-выражения, notepad++

Есть все строки такого типа:

> https://bbb/bbb/bbb/*2018*/*06*/**a**aa_**a**aa-aaa_**a**aa-aaa-1-aaa.doc

Нужно изменить регистр только первой буквы во всех фразах, которые находятся после последнего / и отделяются _ (помечено жирным). Те, что возле | - | не трогать также, как и весь текст до последнего / и после последнего небуквенного символа до конца строки.

Подсказали 2 варианта:
`\w++(?!.*/)(?!$)`
`[^\W_]++(?!.*/)(?!$)`

Теперь нужен третий вариант, где нужно, чтобы выделялись только те, что возле _, а остальные, которые возле | - | не изменялись.

Comment: Вы уже пытались использовать регулярные выражения, чтобы решить эту проблему? Регистр можно менять с помощью `\U`/`\u` и `\L`/`\l` в шаблоне замены.

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew Питался но правильно сопоставить не получилось.

Comment: Главное для нас понять, что именно вы пытались сделать. Добавьте в вопрос, пожалуйста. Что вы имеете в виду под "словами"? У вас просто список URL в текстовом файле? Или кроме URL там есть ещё какие-то строки, которых нельзя трогать?

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew Только URL, под словами имеется ввиду обычный текст, пробовал (\d)(/\w+) но оно выделяет 8/06 вместо фразы, которая идет после /

Comment: То есть всё-таки не "обычный текст", а только "буквенные подстроки" после ... последнего символа `/` на строке? Или нужна проверка на наличие `http://`/`https://` в начале строки??? Пожалуйста, добавьте конкретику в описание проблемы. `(\d)(/\w+)` находит цифру, `/` и один и более букво-цифровых символов (включая символ `_`), зачем вы вообще цифру пытались найти? Или "слова", которые надо изменить, находятся именно после цифры + последнего `/`?

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew Надо только изменить регистр на прописной первых букв фраз после последнего `/`, в данном примере **a**aa_**a**aa-**a**aa_**a**aa-**a**aa-1-**a**aa.doc

Comment: Да, но ведь `doc` не меняется. Какое тут правило? До расширения? Или просто последнее "слово" нельзя трогать?

Comment: Ладно, попробуйте `\w++(?!.*/)(?!$)` => `\u$0`

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew Работает только для фраз после `-`, а те что после `_` не хочет.

Comment: Да, ведь `\w` находит знаки `_`. Используйте `[^\W_]++(?!.*/)(?!$)`

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew а почему так работают два плюса? нигде в доках не видел такой информации

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew и где почитать про модификатооры в строке замены \u ?

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew И напоследок теперь нужно изменить только после `_`, а `-` не изменять

Answer (score 0):

Попробуй так `(.*)\/(\w)`. В первом кармане читается всё до последнего вхождения    `/`, а потом первая буква

А вообще регулярки удобно разбирать в https://regex101.com/